# How can I get post meta value in wp_add_inline_style?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to get meta value of my metabox with wp_add_inline_style for styling. But i don't finding any way for solution it. Is there any idea or way to make it working. any way to get meta value in a callback function?

```
 <?php

function my_styles_method($dipto_section) {

    wp_enqueue_style(
        'custom-style',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/main.css'
    );

        global $dipto_section;

$dipto_section_meta = get_post_meta($dipto_section['section'],'dipto-section-services01', true);

$custom_css = '';

foreach ($dipto_section_meta['services-items'] as $link){

        $custom_css .='
                .mycolor{
                        background:'.esc_attr($link['service-single-color']).';
                }';
}
        wp_add_inline_style( 'custom-style', $custom_css );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_styles_method' );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`get_post_meta` method all accept an **ID** as first parameter, expecting that as **page id** or **post id**.

In your code `$dipto_section['section']` does not seems as **ID**, may that is the reason of not getting the post meta value.

Code is quite correct to add inline style, just the point mentioned is need to corrected.

For your help an example code :

```
function my_styles_method($dipto_section) 
{

     wp_enqueue_style('custom-style',get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/main.css');
     $page_bg=get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'<meta-key>',true);
     $page_bg_css.='#page { background:'.$page_bg.' !important; }';
     wp_add_inline_style( 'custom-style', $page_bg_css );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_styles_method' );
```